# $P(X < Y)$ using conditional probability

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. random variables with Exponential$(\lambda)$ distribution. Using conditioning, determine **a)** $P(X < Y)$ and **b)** the distribution function of $X + Y$.

**Attempt:**

I thought I'd calculate the probability with $P(X < Y) = P(X < y |Y = y)$. To do that you first determine the conditional density, then calculate $P(X < y |Y = y)$. So,

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. Then the conditional distribution is

$$ f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{f_X(x)f_Y(y)}{f_X(x)}, ~~x>0,~~y>0 $$

That is

$$ f_{X|Y}(x|y) = f_X(x),~~x>0,~~~y>0 $$

By this point I'm already thinking I'm doing it totally wrong because when is a problem that easy, right? Anyway, continuing this line of reasoning you get

$$ P(X < x|Y = y) = \int_{0}^{y}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx = F_X(y) = 1 - e^{-\lambda y}$$

> **Official Answer**:
>   $P(X < Y) = 1/2 $.

Since my answer for **a)** is wrong, I didn't even try **b)**.

Comment: $P(X<Y)\neq P(X<y| Y=y)$

Comment: Try the law of total probability $P(X<Y)=\int_0^\infty P(X<y|Y=y)f_Y(y)dy$

Comment: Also maybe a typo but you wrote the expression for $f(y|x)$ (you are dividing by $f_X$ despite wishing to compute $f(x|y)$ which requires dividing by $f_Y$)

Comment: Since $P(X=Y)=0$ we must have $P(X<Y)=P(Y<X)=\frac 12$.

Comment: @NapD.Lover that was a mistake made by copying from my notebook too fast. Sorry. At least it doesn’t make any difference

Comment: @lulu that is a nice trick, however in an exam I’d have to actually do the math with conditional probability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X<Y) &= \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(X<Y\mid Y=y) f_Y(y)\ \mathsf dy\\
&=\int_0^\infty \int_0^y f_X(x)\ \mathsf dx\ f_Y(y)\ \mathsf dy\\
&=\int_0^\infty \int_0^y \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\ \mathsf dx \lambda e^{-\lambda y}\ \mathsf dy\\
&=\int_0^\infty (1-e^{-\lambda y})\lambda e^{-\lambda y}\ \mathsf dy\\
&=\frac12.
\end{align}

For the second part, convolution is the simplest method; for $t\geqslant 0$ the density of $Z:=X+Y$ is 
\begin{align}
f_Z(t) &= (f_X\star f_Y)(t)\\
&= \int_{\mathbb R}f_X(s)f_Y(t-s)\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \int_0^t \lambda e^{-\lambda s}\lambda e^{-\lambda(t-s)}\ \mathsf ds\\
&= \lambda^2\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t \ \mathsf ds\\
&= \lambda(\lambda t)e^{-\lambda t}.
\end{align}
I suppose there is a way to obtain this by conditioning but the computations would likely be more complicated.